# Load static Html file in MVC View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to load a static html file into an MVC View. 
I can view the file using "return Redirect("staticHtmlFile") but I am looking to load the file into a view and have a friendly url.
Example:
Folder called "Ford" which has a html file and related css and images.

the url to show this file should look something like this "http://foo/cars/ford"

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this.

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can `return File("Server path to file")`.

However, you should convert that file to an MVC view instead.

Comment: Can you also make a route directly to a static file?

Comment: @MichaelHaren: Only by making your own `IRouteHandler`.

Comment: Guys, if I make a route directly to a static file would it be possible to have a friendly url. If so how do I go about creating it.